# C function crashed at array parameter

Tags: c, embedded

I write a function like:

```
void func1(char chx[], int y) 
{
    int wsn = 0;

    wsn = *(int *) (&chx[2]);
    if (wsn == 0) {
    ...
    }
 }
```

Compiler works well, no warning, no error. But when the code is running, seems it get a wild pointer. the code crashed.
But code like the following works well:

```
wsn = (chx[5]<< 24) + (chx[4] << 16) + (chx[3] << 8) + chx[2];
```

Wonder why it was crashed

Comment: What platform?  Some machines don't like it if you pass a misaligned address and try to treat it as an `int *`.  For example, many RISC machines require the address of a 4-byte quantity to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, but an arbitrary `char *` is not necessarily sufficiently aligned.  If you get a `SIGBUS` error instead of a `SIGSEGV`, this is often strongly indicative of the trouble.

Comment: SH 32bit MCU, Renessas product.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I observed in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26824346/c-function-crashed-at-array-parameter/26824568#comment42217813_26824346) to the question, some machines don't like it if you pass a misaligned address and try to treat it as an `int *`. For example, many RISC machines require the address of a 4-byte quantity to be aligned on a 4-byte boundary, but an arbitrary `char *`is not necessarily sufficiently aligned. If you get a `SIGBUS` error instead of a `SIGSEGV`, this is often strongly indicative of the trouble.

Since the [Renesas](http://www.renesas.com/products/mpumcu/superh/) site prominently mentions 'RISC' and [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SuperH) affirms this, I am moderately confident that your problem is that the address passed to `func1()` is not sufficiently well aligned for `&chx[2]` to be valid as a 4-byte (presumably) `int *`.

Your code doing the byte operations works because it only requires the data to be byte aligned, and all data on a byte-addressed machine is byte aligned.

You could consider using:

```
void func1(char chx[], int y) 
{
    int wsn = 0;
    int *ip = (int *)&chx[2];
    if ((uintptr_t)ip & 0x3 == 0)
        wsn = *ip;
    else
        wsn = (chx[5]<< 24) + (chx[4] << 16) + (chx[3] << 8) + chx[2];
    if (wsn == 0)
    {
        …
    }
}
```

But you may do just as well with the shift expression anyway.  One thing to watch, though; those `+` operators should perhaps be `|` operators, especially if plain `char` is a signed type.  If it works as it stands, then plain `char` is probably an unsigned type.  Both are allowed by standard C, but which is used has to be documented.